# Get source data for XYscatter chart

Tags: office-js

> Using Excel.Chart Object able to read Y-axes data but not X-axes data.
>   How to get X-axes data or Source data of chart.
>   Using Office js latest version.

[image: sample chart]
Using Excel.Chart Object able to read Y-axes data but not X-axes data.

How to get X-axes data or Source data of chart.

Answer (score 0):

At present there is no Office.js API that can get axes data from Chart. It is a good suggestion. Please go to Office Developer Suggestion Box and suggest it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sai for your post, we have logged a feature request(3566367) as backlog to track this issue.
Would you please share us your scenario for this API ? therefore we can have good understanding for the priority of this API ask.

Update

This API is now in beta preview, would you please validate? Thanks.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.chartseries?view=excel-js-preview#getdimensionvalues-dimension-

Comment: Thanks Raymond for update,  I wanted to reuse the chart by storing it in DB. Since I need to render the same chart, I need the charts source data while extracting the chart.

Comment: Yes, we are working on it, you can try it out with this preview API, getDimensionValues, let us know if this unblock your scenario. thanks

Comment: Yes, tried the same with preview API, but data is returned with general number format so how to get the format of data types ? suppose if it is a date - @RaymondLu

Comment: I think you may parse the string. and figure out whether the string represent a date or other format.

Comment: getDimensionValues returned date as 43988 so how to identify this value as date - 
 @RaymondLu